# how do i create a strong named interop dll for shdocvw.dll

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, interop, bho, strongname

I have a Browser Helper Object project in c# that (obviously) references shdocvw.dll. I think I want to create a strongly named interop dll for shdocvw.dll. How do I do this - I've seen a bunch of suggestions out there with aximp.exe and tlimp but I'm not clear how they fit together.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use tlbimp with a /keyfile:FileName or /keycontainer:FileName switch to do this. Or I think you used to be able to do it in the IDE, simply by adding a COM reference (there was a checkbox to apply the same key to such).

```
sn -k new.snk
tlbimp shdocvw.dll /out:axshdocvw.dll /keyfile:new.snk
```

Obviously you could use your existing key...

You might also want to check that `WebBrowser` doesn't already do everything you need...

Comment: _aximp %WINDIR%\system32\shdocvw.dll /keyfile=PublicPrivateKeyFile.snk_  also may generate signed AxSHDocVw.dll and SHDocVw.dll for you